# What type should the method return?

Tags: typescript

i try to use TypeScript, but i little bit confused.

i have interface:

```js
interface INode {
  parent: INode | null;
  child: INode | null;
  
  value: any;

  insert(value: any): this; // (or INode or i don't know)
}
```

and class which implements this interface:

```js
class Node implements INode {
  left: INode | null;
  right: INode | null;
  
  constructor(public value: any, public parent: INode | null = null) {}

  insert(value: any): this { // Type 'Node' is not assignable to type 'this'.
    if(value == this.value) {
      return this;
    }
    return new (<typeof Node>this.constructor)(value, this);// i've find this way in google
  }
}
```

What type should `insert()` return ?
i've tried made:

```js
insert(value: any): this {
  if(value == this.value) {
    return this;
  }

  return new (<typeof Node>this.constructor)(value, this) as this;
}
```

but it's looks strange and little bit wrong;

class `Node` will be Extended and `insert()` method should return right type;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insert(value: any)` function should return the type `INode`. Specific implementations can then return `Node` or a new `DerivedNode` which are all assignable to `INode`.

Comment: hm, ok, i got it thanks a lot.
But then i've other trouble:
object of class which implements INode interface is not comparable with INode:

```javascript
interface INode {
  copy(node: INode): void;
}

class Node implements INode {
  ...
  copy(node: Node) { ... } // Property 'node' in type 'Node' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'INode'
}
```
why? 
Node implements interface, and is the narrow subtype

Comment: i've faced a problem: `insert(value: any): INode { return this; }` Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'INode'